# property about topological space

Tags: general-topology

I have a question.

Let $f,g$ be continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$, $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ a topological space under ordered topology. Then prove that the set $\{x \in X \ | \ f(x) < g(x)\}$ is open.
  I want to know that what intrisic property of order makes it possible.

Comment: Do you know what is the basis for the order topology?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the map $(f,g)\colon X\to Y\times Y$. This map is continuous because $f$ and $g$ are.

Your set $\{x \in X \mid f(x) < g(x)\}$ is the preimage under $(f,g)$ of the set $\{(a,b) \in Y\times Y \mid a < b\}$.

Now, the only thing that remains to prove is that $\{(a,b) \in Y\times Y \mid a < b\}\subseteq Y\times Y$ is open.

This follows from the definition of the [Order topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology) on $Y$. Do you need help with that?

Answer (score 1):

Hey i found this somewhere on the net. See **problem 5** in the given link:

http://www.math.uiowa.edu/~jsimon/COURSES/M132Fall07/M132Fall07_Exam1_Solutions.pdf